# Limit of the Sum

Tags: calculus, limits

If $ \lim_{x \to x_1}(f(x))$ exists but $\lim_{x \to x_1}(g(x))$ doesn't, then can we say whether or not $\lim_{x \to x_1}(f(x)+g(x))$ exists?

Comment: Consider $\lim(f(x)+g(x))-\lim f(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. **Hint**. If both $\lim_{x\to x_1} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to x_1} h(x)$ exist, what can you say about $\lim_{x\to x_1} h(x) - f(x)$? Now use this for $h(x) = f(x) + g(x)$ above.